# Extracting certain words from column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have csv file like below in a column 'filename' and I would like to have the label column name only the word before underscore (_)

For example: output like below

```
filename                                                      label
```

How can I extract only those words from following column and paste into label column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str.split()` method, and assuming that you import your csv as a Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_path')
df['label'] = df['filename'].str.split('____').str[0]
```

Comment: 'KeyError: '/home/sharad/data1.csv''

Comment: Do you know the encoding and the delimiter of your csv ? Try `pd.read_csv('./home/sharad/data1.csv', delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8-sig')`

Comment: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/sharad/data1.csv' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
This is the enconding of my csv.
Moreover I have tried above line code and with pd.read_csv('./home/sharad/data1.csv', delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8-sig') still facing same issue

Comment: Please place your csv in the same folder as your python script. What does `pd.read_csv('data1.csv',  encoding='UFT-8', encoding_errors='ignore')` gives you ?

Comment: 'import pandas as pd
'''df = pd.read_csv('/home/sharad/data1.csv', delimiter='"', encoding="utf-8-sig",encoding_errors='ignore')
print(df)  '                                                                                                                                               used this code output of print(df) is the first coloumn

Comment: Thank you it worked.But I have question How do I save a Csv file with extraction

Comment: `df.to_csv('out.csv', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240320/discussion-between-nassimh-and-alpha).

Answer (score 0):

```
df['label'] = df.apply(lambda row:row['filename'].split('____')[0], axis=1)
```

Comment: what is 'y' in above line. 
I am getting keyerror for this.

Comment: mb that's just your filename

Comment: I am getting key error.
KeyError: '/home/sharad/data1.csv'

Comment: can you show the traceback?

Comment: `filename` in the code above is the name of your column

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try it

```
import padndas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('file_path')

def extract_label(filename):
    rerurn filename.split('____')[0]

data['label'] = data['filename'].apply(lambda filename:extract_label(filename))
```

Comment: getting key error

Answer (score 0):

Please try this line on your code.

```
df['Label'] = [x.split("___")[0] for x in df['filename']]
```

Comment: Still facing an keyerror.  Instead of filename should I give only file name or the path of filename. I am trying with both by giving filename and path of filename. I am facing an issue with both

Comment: Please print df.columns to know your correct column names.